# How to create another dictionary which contains string

Tags: python, dictionary

I am trying to extract the dictionary which contains string

dictionary is below

```
[ { "id": "1", "name": "A", "businessArea": [ "Accounting" ], "Designation": [ "L2" ], "Location":"NY" }, 
{ "id": "2", "name": "B", "businessArea": [ "Engineering" ], "Role": [ "Tester","Developer" ], "Designation": [ "L1" ],"Location":"CA" },
 { "id": "3", "name": "C", "businessArea": [ "Engineering" ], "Role": [ "Developer" ], "Designation": [ "L1" ],"Location":"NY" }]
```

I am trying to extract

- the `businessArea` is  `Engineering` and,
- `Role` which is `Tester or Developer` and
- `Designation` is `L1` and
- `Location` is `NY`

Code is below

```
def get_set(d,field):
    return {d[field]} if isinstance(d[field], str) else set(d[field])
    
# we use this to filter
def validate(d):
    if 'Role' in d or `businessArea` in d or `Designation` in d or `Location` in d :
        return get_set(d,'Role').intersection({'Developer','Tester'}) and \
               get_set(d,'businessArea').intersection({'Engineering'}) and \
               get_set(d,'Designation').intersection({'L1'}) and \
               get_set(d,'Location').intersection({'NY'})

result = [d for d in test if validate(d)]
```

- I am getting null list

Expected out is `[{ "id": "3", "name": "C", "businessArea": [ "Engineerring" ], "Role": [ "Developer" ], "Designation": [ "L1" ],"Location":"NY" }]`

Adding one more dictionary to test

`[{ 'id': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Accounting' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Accounting' } ],'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }, ] }, { 'id': '2', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Research' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Accounting' } ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Tester' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }, ] }, { 'id': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Research' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Accounting' } ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Developer' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }] }]`

second dictionary to test

```
[{'_index': '1',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '1',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'id': '1',
   'name': 'A',
   'businessArea': [{'id': '25', 'name': 'Accounting'}],
   'Role': ['Developer'],
   'Designation': ['L2'],
   'Location': 'NY'}},
 {'_index': '1',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '2',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'id': '2',
   'name': 'B',
   'businessArea': [{'id': '25', 'name': 'Engineering'}],
   'Role': ['Tester', 'Developer'],
   'Designation': ['L1'],
   'Location': 'NY'}},
 {'_index': '1',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '3',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'id': '3',
   'name': 'C',
   'businessArea': [{'id': '25', 'name': 'Engineering'}],
   'Role': ['Tester', 'Developer'],
   'Designation': ['L1'],
   'Location': 'NY'}}]
```

Comment: You should provide your values and execution trace with your posting.  Where is the expected operation breaking down?  Is it with accessing the values?  With the `if` statement, such that your function returns `None` by default?  Is it an empty set from the comparisons?

Comment: wha tis is the issue with my code

Comment: I'll wait for you to address the debugging points I raised.

Comment: To avoid key error in function get_set, change all `or` to `and` in function validate and your current code runs successfully.

Comment: @DarrylG , how to do that if i give `and` it is will throw err right, i need to check whethere those key is present in my dictionary or not

Comment: @Prune first need to check key exists or not, at one shot how check all the key present or not , if present

Comment: @Nons--I posted what I meant by changing or to and.  By using and you are assured all the required keys exists, thus avoiding a key error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Fix of Original Code**

You can get your code to run by replacing or with and in if statement in function validate

```
def get_set(d,field):
    return {d[field]} if isinstance(d[field], str) else set(d[field])
    
# we use this to filter
def validate(d):
    # change or to and in if statement
    if 'Role' in d and 'businessArea' in d and 'Designation' in d and 'Location' in d :
        return get_set(d,'Role').intersection({'Developer','Tester'}) and \
               get_set(d,'businessArea').intersection({'Engineering'}) and \
               get_set(d,'Designation').intersection({'L1'}) and \
               get_set(d,'Location').intersection({'NY'})

test = [ { "id": "1", "name": "A", "businessArea": [ "Accounting" ], "Designation": [ "L2" ], "Location":"NY" }, 
{ "id": "2", "name": "B", "businessArea": [ "Engineering" ], "Role": [ "Tester","Developer" ], "Designation": [ "L1" ],"Location":"CA" },
 { "id": "3", "name": "C", "businessArea": [ "Engineering" ], "Role": [ "Developer" ], "Designation": [ "L1" ],"Location":"NY" }]

result = [d for d in test if validate(d)]   

print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[{'id': '3',
  'name': 'C',
  'businessArea': ['Engineering'],
  'Role': ['Developer'],
  'Designation': ['L1'],
  'Location': 'NY'}]
```

**New Algorithm to Handle Nested Dictionaries**

```
def contains(item, field, values):
    '''
       Search through nested dictionary starting a key field
       to find if a value is in values
    '''
    if field:
        item = item.get(field)      # Get value of field
    if item is None:
        return None                 # Done if field not found
    if isinstance(item, list):
        return any(contains(v, None, values) for v in item)  # recursively check if any value in list in values
    if isinstance(item, dict):
        return any(contains(v, None, values) for v in item.values())  # recursively check if any value in dictionary in values
    return item in values       # Not list or dict, so check if item in values
    
def validate(d):
    return contains(d, 'Role', {'Developer','Tester'}) and \
           contains(d, 'businessArea', {'Engineering'}) and \
           contains(d, 'Designation', {'L1'}) and \
           contains(d, 'Location', {'NY'})
```

**Tests**

*Test 1*

```
test = [ { "id": "1", "name": "A", "businessArea": [ "Accounting" ], "Designation": [ "L2" ], "Location":"NY" }, 
{ "id": "2", "name": "B", "businessArea": [ "Engineering" ], "Role": [ "Tester","Developer" ], "Designation": [ "L1" ],"Location":"CA" },
 { "id": "3", "name": "C", "businessArea": [ "Engineering" ], "Role": [ "Developer" ], "Designation": [ "L1" ],"Location":"NY" }]
```

*Output 1*

```
[{'id': '3', 'name': 'C', 'businessArea': ['Engineering'], 'Role': ['Developer'], 'Designation': ['L1'], 'Location': 'NY'}]
```

*Test 2*

```
test = [{'id': '1',   'name': 'A',   'businessArea':[{'id': '25', 'name': 'Accounting'}],   'Role': ['Developer'],   'Designation': ['L2'],   'Location': 'NY'},  {'id': '2',   'name': 'B',   'businessArea':[{'id': '25', 'name': 'Engineering'}],   'Role': ['Tester', 'Developer'],   'Designation': ['L1'],   'Location': 'NY'},  {'id': '3',   'name': 'C',   'businessArea':[{'id': '25', 'name': 'Engineering'}],   'Role': ['Tester', 'Developer'],   'Designation': ['L1'],   'Location': 'NY'}]
result = [d for d in t if validate(d)]  
print(result)
```

*Output 2*

```
[{'id': '2', 'name': 'B', 'businessArea': [{'id': '25', 'name': 'Engineering'}], 'Role': ['Tester', 'Developer'], 'Designation': ['L1'], 'Location': 'NY'}, {'id': '3', 'name': 'C', 'businessArea': [{'id': '25', 'name': 'Engineering'}], 'Role': ['Tester', 'Developer'], 'Designation': ['L1'], 'Location': 'NY'}]
```

*Test 3*

```
test = [{ 'id': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Accounting' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Accounting' } ],'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }, ] }, { 'id': '2', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Research' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Accounting' } ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Tester' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }, ] }, { 'id': '1', 'name': 'Group1', 'BusinessArea': [ { 'id': '14', 'name': 'Research' }, { 'id': '3', 'name': 'Accounting' } ], 'Role': [ { 'id': '5032', 'name': 'Developer' }, { 'id': '5033', 'name': 'Developer' } ], 'Designation': [ { 'id': '16', 'name': 'L1' }, { 'id': '20', 'name': 'L2' }, { 'id': '25', 'name': 'L2' }] }]
result = [d for d in t if validate(d)] 
print(result)
```

*Output 3*

```
[{'id': '2', 'name': 'B', 'businessArea': [{'id': '25', 'name': 'Engineering'}], 'Role': ['Tester', 'Developer'], 'Designation': ['L1'], 'Location': 'NY'}, {'id': '3', 'name': 'C', 'businessArea': [{'id': '25', 'name': 'Engineering'}], 'Role': ['Tester', 'Developer'], 'Designation': ['L1'], 'Location': 'NY'}]
```

*Test 4* (2nd dictionary in question)

```
test = [{'_index': '1',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '1',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'id': '1',
   'name': 'A',
   'businessArea': [{'id': '25', 'name': 'Accounting'}],
   'Role': ['Developer'],
   'Designation': ['L2'],
   'Location': 'NY'}},
 {'_index': '1',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '2',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'id': '2',
   'name': 'B',
   'businessArea': [{'id': '25', 'name': 'Engineering'}],
   'Role': ['Tester', 'Developer'],
   'Designation': ['L1'],
   'Location': 'NY'}},
 {'_index': '1',
  '_type': '_doc',
  '_id': '3',
  '_score': 1.0,
  '_source': {'id': '3',
   'name': 'C',
   'businessArea': [{'id': '25', 'name': 'Engineering'}],
   'Role': ['Tester', 'Developer'],
   'Designation': ['L1'],
   'Location': 'NY'}}]

result = [d for d in t if validate(d)] 
print(result)
```

*Output*

```
[{'id': '2', 'name': 'B', 'businessArea': [{'id': '25', 'name': 'Engineering'}], 'Role': ['Tester', 'Developer'], 'Designation': ['L1'], 'Location': 'NY'}, {'id': '3', 'name': 'C', 'businessArea': [{'id': '25', 'name': 'Engineering'}], 'Role': ['Tester', 'Developer'], 'Designation': ['L1'], 'Location': 'NY'}]
```

Comment: if my businessarea is list of arrays then how to loop.  `[{'id': '1',
  'name': 'A',
  'businessArea':[{'id': '25', 'name': 'Accounting'}],
  'Role': ['Developer'],
  'Designation': ['L2'],
  'Location': 'NY'},
 {'id': '2',
  'name': 'B',
  'businessArea':[{'id': '25', 'name': 'Engineerring'}],
  'Role': ['Tester', 'Developer'],
  'Designation': ['L1'],
  'Location': 'NY'},
 {'id': '3',
  'name': 'C',
  'businessArea':[{'id': '25', 'name': 'Engineerring'}],
  'Role': ['Tester', 'Developer'],
  'Designation': ['L1'],
  'Location': 'NY'}]`

Comment: @Nons-in this case businessarea  is a list containing one dictionary.  Is this the worst case, or could it be more complex?

Comment: like businessarea, role also be list of dictionary with lot of id's, and I need to check `name` in each attribute (like businessarea['name'], 'Role'['Name']')

Comment: i have added one more dictionary to test

Comment: @Nons--added a new algorithm that can handle arbitrarily nested dictionaries.

Comment: I have added one more dictionary same like, but its not working

Comment: can you check once and guide so that i can fix

Comment: @Nons--not sure of the meaning of the request.  Can you explain it further?

Comment: @Nons--added Test 4 which is the result of 2nd dictionary in posted question.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
myList = [ { "id": "1", "name": "A", "businessArea": [ "Accounting" ], "Designation": [ "L2" ], "Location":"NY" }, 
{ "id": "2", "name": "B", "businessArea": [ "Engineerring" ], "Role": [ "Tester","Developer" ], "Designation": [ "L1" ],"Location":"CA" },
 { "id": "3", "name": "C", "businessArea": [ "Engineerring" ], "Role": [ "Developer" ], "Designation": [ "L1" ],"Location":"NY" }]
for x in myList:
  if (("Tester" in x['Role'] or "Developer" in x['Role']) and (x["Designation"] == "L1")) and (x["Location"] == "NY"): 
    print(x)
```

Comment: you can see first dictionary does not have `Role` so it will throw key error

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo on your examples (`engineerring`):

```
[ { "id": "1", "name": "A", "businessArea": [ "Accounting" ], "Designation": [ "L2" ], "Location":"NY" }, 
{ "id": "2", "name": "B", "businessArea": [ "Engineering" ], "Role": [ "Tester","Developer" ], "Designation": [ "L1" ],"Location":"CA" },
 { "id": "3", "name": "C", "businessArea": [ "Engineering" ], "Role": [ "Developer" ], "Designation": [ "L1" ],"Location":"NY" }]
```

Comment: It is the answer. There was no issue with your code. Try running it now.

Comment: u can see in first dictionary there is no `Role`

Comment: You have to account for the case some key is not present, then.